# How to extend the user model to add more fields to it

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using the default User model that django provides. But I would like to add more fields to it that are specific to my application.

I've done the following but it doesn't seem to be working. I am trying to add a field called `company_name` and to test whether it works I try to update it using the rest API.

last line of settings.py:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'demo.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'demo.wsgi.application'
...
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "demo.UserProfile"
```

Models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I'm not sure whether it is setting the company_name property but since it isn't returning it..I'm assuming what I've done doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

But you haven't extended the User model at all, you've created a separate model which links to it via a 1-1 relation. So you shouldn't expect a JSON dump of the User model to include your profile fields.

I don't know what framework you are using to generate that REST output, but maybe you can extend the serializer to include the related fields. But a better approach would be to actually use a custom user model: rather than linking User to a Profile, extend the AbstractUser class with your own fields and tell Django to use your model in place of the default. This is [fully documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: I'm using the rest_framework. I'm new to django and it seemed the easiest to just create a new model and link it to user. I'll go through the documentation you suggested.

Comment: I've edited the question. I'm actually happy with the Django user model and just want to add fields to it as suggested in this documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user . I've changed my question to show I've extended the `AbstractUser`. I'm just trying to see how to get and update my custom field using rest. I'm very lost.